# Twentythirteen toggle menu in wordpress not working

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, themes

I'm having an issue where I'm using the twentythirteen theme of wordpress. Normally, if you condense your window screen to a narrow view then the navigation works if you click "menu" and can see the pages below.  However, it does not work in the theme that I have modified... is there an easy way so that I can "enable" it possibly?

Or, if not, is there a way I can have a hide / show version of this menu enabled?

This is the URL for the dev site... shrink your browser narrow to see how it would work if you click "menu"

EDIT: Fixed this.. what I did was just use a different hide / show toggle in jQuery that calls the mobile navigation menu. http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-toggle-example-to-display-and-hide-content/

Comment: Does the console say anything?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not sure what you mean by console... can you please elaborate?

Comment: edited my original post w url for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed this.. what I did was just use a different hide / show toggle in jQuery that calls the mobile navigation menu. http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-toggle-example-to-display-and-hide-content/

Answer (score 0):

Without us seeing a URL and being able to see any javascript errors with the mobile menu switcher or code markup errors:

1) Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what's loading on your site and see any javascript errors.

2) Use the W3C Validator http://validator.w3.org/ to check for markup errors, since you mention you have modified the theme. See http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//bayarddev.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654

Comment: OK, then fix your code errors; you have some in the header area and with the nav toggle.

Comment: @Mixmastermichael could you please share code which lines are you replaced. I have used customized one for my self my and i have same problem too. In other place you said you have fixed but how ?

Comment: Sure, this is actually the link I used to do this... http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-toggle-example-to-display-and-hide-content/ Just made it only visible in the responsive version of my site, so wrapped it in a div, put a display: none; in the desktop and display: block in the mobile version.